# How are continuous streams of projectiles created in programming? [Say: Gaming]

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, collision-detection

I'm creating a side-scroller video game for my final project in my grade 12 programming class. Right now I have  nice delta-timer my partner made for me, a flying ship, asteroids, and a scrolling background. I've added a few basic things such as collision detection between asteroids and the ship, and ship movement. Now, my next steps are implementing random enemy spawns, and projectiles (laser beams :D) from both ships. Implementing random enemy spawns should fun and relatively easy, however **I'm struggling with figuring out how I will create so many bullets that will fit on the screen. I need bullets from the enemy, and the ship (player controlled).**

How can I achieve this? I know there are probably many answers to this question, but I would really like to see the types of approaches people have to this problem.

So far I have thought that:
a) I could make the game have a (say) 200 bullets max on the screen
b) I could make a dynamic array (I believe this term means the array gets bigger or smaller), that way I don't limit the amount of possible projectiles

...and then I'm afraid that all these bullets will cause lag from all the collision processing that will happen.

Please shed some light on this, and help guide me along the path to an efficient; well executed; side-scroller game.

Thanks,

Guest dude

Comment: I don't think this question has a fixed answer. Depending on your project, you can try multiple things. Limiting bullets is one way, reducing the footprint of collision processing (don't do it for every bullet, but just for those which are near other object) is another.

Comment: Ah I see, that last bit helps. I know this question doesn't have a definitive answer and that's why I posted it, I wanted to know what ways people approach this problem.

Comment: Well, thing is you can approach in multiple ways depending on what you are building. That collision processing trick won't work for those galaga style games. In first person shooter, you can use "gun getting heated" trick. You can also add a long reload time. Or use passive bullets which just fly in a direction and handle the collision processing on the other objects instead. 

I am not sure, if stackoverflow is a right place for this type of theoretical questions. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ allows this type of questions. You will have better luck there.

Comment: Create a list of bullet objects and do the collision processing on the objects that the bullets could hit. You would of course need some processing on the bullet to check if it is still on screen of course.